# Submitting Job to Remote Apache Spark Server

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Apache Spark (v1.6.1) started as service on Ubuntu (10.10.0.102) machine, using `./start-all.sh`.

Now need to submit job to this server remotely using Java API.

Following is Java client code running from different machine (10.10.0.95).

```
    String mySqlConnectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?user=sec&password=sec";

    String jars[] = new String[] {"/home/.m2/repository/com/databricks/spark-csv_2.10/1.4.0/spark-csv_2.10-1.4.0.jar", 
            "/home/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-csv/1.1/commons-csv-1.1.jar", 
            "/home/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/6.0.2/mysql-connector-java-6.0.2.jar"};
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("sparkCSVWriter")
            .setMaster("spark://10.10.0.102:7077")
            .setJars(jars);

    JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(javaSparkContext);

    Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
    options.put("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    options.put("url", mySqlConnectionUrl);
    options.put("dbtable", "(select p.FIRST_NAME from person p) as firstName");

    DataFrame dataFrame = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(options).load();

    dataFrame.write()
        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("delimiter", "|")
        .option("quote", "\"")
        .option("quoteMode", QuoteMode.NON_NUMERIC.toString())
        .option("escape", "\\")
        .save("persons.csv");

    Configuration hadoopConfiguration = javaSparkContext.hadoopConfiguration();
    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfiguration);

    FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path("persons.csv"), hdfs, new Path("\home\persons1.csv"), true, hadoopConfiguration, new String());
```

As per code need to convert RDBMS data to csv/json using Spark. But when I run this client application, able to connect to remote spark server but in console continuously receiving following WARN message

```
WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

And at server side on Spark UI in running applications > executor summary > stderr log, received following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /192.168.56.1:53112
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:216)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:183)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /192.168.56.1:53112
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    ... 1 more
```

But there no any IP address configured as `192.168.56.1`. So is there any configuration missing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually my client machine(10.10.0.95) is Windows machine. When I tried to submit Spark job using another Ubuntu machine(10.10.0.155), I am able to run same Java client code successfully.

As I debugged in Windows client environment, when I submit spark job following log displayed,

```
INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@192.168.56.1:61552]
INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 61552.
INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 2.4 GB
INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4044.
INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://192.168.56.1:4044
```

As per log line number 2, its register client with 192.168.56.1.

Elsewhere, in Ubuntu client

```
INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@10.10.0.155:42786]
INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 42786.
INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 511.1 MB
INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://10.10.0.155:4040
```

As per log line number 2, its register client with 10.10.0.155 same as actual IP address.

If anybody find what is the problem with Windows client, let community know.

**[UPDATE]**

I am running this whole environment in Virtual Box. Windows machine is my host and Ubuntu is guest. And Spark installed in Ubuntu machine. In Virtual box environment Virtual box installing `Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Netwotk` with IPv4 address : `192.168.56.1`. And Spark registering this IP as client IP instead of actual IP address `10.10.0.95`.